# Defining dask worker resources for a dataframe operation

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am applying multiple operations to a dask dataframe. Can I define distributed worker resource requirements for particular operation?

e.g. I call something like:

```
df.fillna(value="").map_partitions(...).map(...)
```

I want to specify resource requirement for *map_partitions()* (potentially different than the ones for *map()*), but seems like the method does not accept *resources* parameter.

PS. Alternatively, I figured out that I can call *client.persist()* after *map_partitions()* and specify resources in this call, but this immediately triggers the computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify resource constraints on particular parts of your computation when you call `compute` or `persist` by providing the intermediate collection.

```
x = dd.read_csv(...)
y = x.map_partitions(func)
z = y.map(func2)

z.compute(resources={tuple(y._keys()): {'GPU': 1}})
```

Thank you for the question, I went to include a link to the documentation about this feature and found that it was undocumented.  I'll fix shortly.

It looks like today there is a bug where the intermediate keys may be optimized out in some situations (though this is less likely for dataframe operation), so you may also want to pass the `optimize_graph=False` keyword.

```
z.compute(resources={tuple(y._keys()): {'GPU': 1}}, optimize_graph=False)
```

See https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1362

Comment: Also there is a bug when trying to achieve this with `to_parquet` in the graph - see https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6758